# Windows 7 says 1600x900 resolution, monitor reports 1400x900

Tags: windows-7, resolution

A new Intel i5 Windows 7 machine is connected to a known-good VGA cable via a DVI adaptor to a 1600x900 LCD monitor.

The adapter unfortunately knocks out the pnp/edid bit so you have to specify the resolution yourself.

However, choosing 1600x900 from the menu and pressing apply, I can see that it's not right. Pressing the monitors OSD menu tells me that the monitor believes the signal it's receiving is actually 1440x900 not 1600x900. Which would definitely account for the distortion I'm seeing.

Is there a way to tell Windows to behave? :-) Has anyone experience of this oddness [and found a fix]?

Comment: We have a [faq]. You should read it.

Comment: yep, read that, what's your beef? I am a professional, installing machines in an office. I have a particular problem with this machine that I thought others experienced in W7 (I am not) may have come across.

Comment: Why are you using a VGA cable? It's 2012, where's the DVI, HDMI, or DP connection?

Comment: It is an old(ish) monitor, bought to work on old box with VGA only. I have replaced the box, but there's nothing wrong with the monitor, so am not replacing that.

Comment: It sounds like the entire problem is the adapter.  I would try using a DVI-I Dual Link Male to VGA Male cable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start with a different adapter, if the one you have is messing with the edid/pnp. If the two systems can't agree on the resolution that's being transferred, then that sounds like a timing / sync issue, which a faulty adapter is not going to help.

Comment: I think it's probably a quirky monitor. But I'll get a lead and see. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Different adaptor sorted it.